# Errors on importing MoPub SDK on Android in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mopub

I'm facing a lot of errors while importing MoPub SDK to my workspace. It shows over 5000 errors.

[image: MoPub SDK errors on import in Eclipse]

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've tried to import as Java Project, then as Android Project. I have set it as library, and referencing to it as a library from my main project.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you,
Wojtek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. After importing the project Eclipse made `Java Build Path` -> `Source`:

- `mopub-sdk/gen`
- `mobup-sdk/src`

But it should be:

- `mopub-sdk/gen`
- `mobup-sdk/src/main/java`

[image: Java Build Path - MoPub SDK source]

Simple `Remove` and then `Add Folder...` solve the issues.

Comment: I encountered something similar too during my first spin with the SDK but 5000 errors topped my count.  Any other development pain points you encountering?  Would love to know.

Comment: Nope, other than that the integration went smoothly.

Comment: can you give me the link of sdk of mopub ?